# error when trying to connect two tables within one php page

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get to retrieve an entire datasbase, so i can print out the results gathered into a table.

when using

```
  $data = mysql_query(SELECT md.*, qr.* FROM moduleDetails md LEFT JOIN qResponses qr ON qr.userno = md.userno)
```

im getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING as an error

Any ideas? new to joining tables.

Comment: Perhaps you need to quote your query string: `$data = mysql_query("SELECT md.*, qr.* FROM moduleDetails md LEFT JOIN qResponses qr ON qr.userno = md.userno");` and don't forget a semi-colon at the end of the line

Comment: Gotta love the small things in life

Comment: You should not have posted this as a new question, I told you in your other thread to do some basic debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Here how it should be

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT md.*, qr.* FROM moduleDetails md LEFT JOIN qResponses qr ON qr.userno = md.userno");
```